# Develop a media player which accept commands from serial port. Is it possible? How to do it?

Tags: serial-port, media-player, microcontroller

I'm trying to develop a media player in which the control commands are comming from serial port like

```
for  play you will get 'P' charcter from serial port.....
for Forward = 'F'
for Reverse = 'R'
for Pause = 'P'
```

These commands are comming from our microcontroller board.
Can anyone help me where should i start? How to do this?
Its going to be very very basic player. No fancy things at all. For e.g. a C program output etc.
I'm going to use it for my presentations. I don't know how to do this so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the commands are coming from, you can pass them to a media player object like Windows Media Player. On Windows, .Net has pretty good support for the Media Player. I am sure the same can be done on other platforms too.

Here's a [reference article for exposing the Media Player to C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and here's another one for [embedding it in a .NET form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Also, take a look at this [Video LAN project page](http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html) (they manage the development of VLC). You can do a lot with the VLC player through command line.

Answer (score 1):

A cross platform media player like VLC can be controlled via command line switches as mentioned **[here](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,10787.msg83803.html#msg83803)**, or via API as explained **[here](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/developer/html/manual.html)**.